# segfault SEGV_ACCERR - Invalid Permissions for object

Tags: c, unix, gcc, segmentation-fault

I have written a C code to shuffle a deck of 52 cards using swapping logic. The code generates a random number between 0 to 53 (52 and 53 are omitted) and then swaps it with the ith index in the array. The code is below.

My issue :
When i comment out display() function call before calling swap() function, the program throws a seg fault. But when i uncomment it and call the display function before calling swap() function , the program works fine and i get the desired output. I dont know why this is happening.

Main Function :

```
int main()
{
char deck[] = {'2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','0','A','J','K','Q'};
char suit[] = {'D','H','S','C'};

char **array,**array1;
array = malloc(sizeof(char *)*52);
array1= array;

srand(time(NULL));

for(int i=0;i<=12;i++)
{
        for(int j=0;j<=3;j++)
        {
                if((*array = malloc(sizeof(char)*2))!=NULL)
                {
                        sprintf(*array,"%c%c",deck[i],suit[j]);
                        *array++;
                }
        }
}

//display(array1); // when i comment this line, the program throws segfault. when i uncomment it the program runs fine. 
swap(array1);
display(array1);
free_array(array1);
return 0;
}
```

And here is the other functions swap and display.

```
void display(char **array)
{
char **temp;
temp = array;

for(int i=0;i<=51;i++)
{
        printf("temp [%s]\n",*temp);
        *temp++;
}

return;
}

void swap(char **array)
{
char **temp;
int x;
temp = array;
char *temp1;

for(int i=0;i<=51;i++)
{
        x = rand()%53;
        if(x == 53 || x == 52)
                continue;

        memcpy(temp1,temp[i],2);   // program segfaults here. 
        memcpy(temp[i],temp[x],2);
        memcpy(temp[x],temp1,2);
}
return;
}
```

Comment: `temp1`is never initialized, neither is `temp`.

Comment: @MichaelWalz `temp = array;` initializes it. You're correct about `temp1`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In swap function -

You are using temp1 with out initializing it.

```
void swap(char **array)
{
  char **temp;
  int x;
  temp = array;
  char temp1[ 2 ];

  for(int i=0;i<=51;i++)
  {
        x = rand()%53;
        if(x == 53 || x == 52)
                continue;

        // need to multiply the indexes by 2
        // allowing for the suit and deck
        memcpy(temp1,temp[ i  ],2);   // program segfaults here. 
        memcpy(temp[ i  ],temp[ x  ],2);
        memcpy(temp[ x  ],temp1,2);
  }
}
```

The above shows temp1 initialized correctly.

I haven't checked the rest of your function, but this will stop the segfault.

Comment: Got it. But how does calling the display() function before calling swap() function removes this issue ? Becuase when i call the display() function before calling swap() function, i dont get the seg fault. Also , why does compiler doesnt give me a warning that the variable is not initialized before its used ?

Comment: @Shri: `temp1` has undefined/random content. Depending on the previous usage of the storage location this can be NULL, -1 or the address of a poem.

Comment: @Shri Do you enable all warnings during compilation?

Comment: I get these list of warnings when i compile with -Wall : 


game7.c: In function 'swap':
game7.c:80: error: 'for' loop initial declaration used outside C99 mode

Comment: @Neil: temp1[52] is not needed . I am mem copying only 2 bytes to temp1. So temp1 can have size as 3 including null terminator. or I can have `*temp1 = malloc(sizeof(char) * 3)` . Is my understanding correct ?

Comment: @Shri you are correct, 52 is high, I could of just used 2 bytes for the array. Memcpy is a long-winded way to copy just two bytes thou. If you are only copying two bytes, you do not need a null terminator plus with malloc, you will also need to free temp1 at the end of the function. Having a char array is just easy to implement, read and debug.

Comment: @Shri - I have updated my answer, so the indexes are correct for the memcpy. I hope you understand why I have multiplied the indexes by 2

Comment: @Neil : Your code gives a core dump because you copy every second element of an array of 52 cards. The for loop runs for 52 times and tries at least one swap for each of the 52 cards in the array.

Comment: @Shri - I should of just left it as is Shri ... I, wrongly assumed you were passing one large buffer in. I've looked at the rest of your snippets and will change the indexes- also I will  apologize for not checking!

Answer (score 1):

You have another UB as well

`sprintf(*array,"%c%c",deck[i],suit[j]);`

you need 3 chars not two as malloc:

`*array = malloc(sizeof(char)*2))`

Comment: do you mean for the null terminator '\0' ?